# Android : not getting GCM Library in extra folder

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-sdk-tools

I want to use GCM Service in my application.

From the SDK manager I am not getting GCM Library in the Extras Folder.

Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Google Play Services library,  which contains the GoogleCloudMessaging class,  which is the new way to register to GCM.